# Importing a matrix of large dimension in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to create an integer matrix of dimensions 20,000*7,000 in matlab. The entries of the matrix are available in excel sheet. When I try to import, it shows memory problem error, or it shows matlab is not responding.

Please give me a solution to import the large matrix.

Comment: Try splitting up your matrix into multiple matrices, and use `xlsread` with a row offset to pick up where you left off for each matrix. Something like reading the first 2000 rows into one matrix, then the next 2000 rows in another matrix, etc.... or better yet, place this all into a 3D matrix or cell array. Also, if it's an integer matrix, it may help if you convert your matrix using an integer type (`uint8/uint16` etc.) instead of relying on MATLAB as it will make the matrix `double` by default.

Comment: Note that a 20,000 x 7,000 matrix of doubles will take up 20000x7000x8 bytes, or around 1.04 GB. If you don't have at least this much memory available, then you won't be able to import your matrix at all.

Comment: It seems that MATLAB is *incredibly* inefficient when reading and writing Excel files. I have around 32GB of free memory on my machine. If I create a new matrix of size 20000x7000 the amount of free memory decreases by around 1GB (which makes sense). If I then try and write it to an Excel file using `xlswrite` it uses an additional 20GB of memory before crashing with "Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC" *and continues to take up around 10GB of memory even after clearing the workspace*. This memory is only reclaimed by closing MATLAB.

Comment: I see similar memory behaviour when trying to read a large Excel file. So the short answer seems to be "don't use `xlswrite` or `xlsread`".

Comment: a (cumbersome) way of solving this without using `xlsread` would be to directly copy the values to a matrix variable in matlab. in R2014b, click Home --> new variable. Then just copy-paste the values from excel in the variable editor. Note: you might still have to split this into smaller blocks to prevent memory issues, and I am not sure whether this actually uses less memory than `xlsread`.